# Message to display for zero byte file in PHP

Tags: php, html, linux

I have **0 byte** file (assume **anil.txt**)under `/nrt/www/AAAA/RRRR/` directory.

Now I need a **PHP Script** where I need to check **anil.txt** file and if it **0 byte** files then I need to display message.

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `filesize` function. You're a newbie, because of that I am adding the code here but please write some code first next time, than you can ask for our help.

Example code:

```
<?php
    $size = filesize('path/to/your/file');

    if ($size === 0) {
     //do something here
    }
```